# Clear all Javascript-applied styles

Tags: javascript, css

Let's say we have this

```
var e = document.getElementById("someElement");
e.style.borderColor = "gold";
e.style.background = "yellow";
e.style.padding = "5px";
// more style modifications via javascript
```

There may have been other styles set inline or in an external CSS file.

Is there a method to clear all Javascript-applied styles? Like `e.style.* = inherit` or `e.removeJavaScriptAppliedStyles()`.

Comment: You could simply remove the `style` attribute assuming there were no hard-coded values applied to the element.

Comment: Be warned that a solution to this will also remove inline styles, not just javascript applied styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<div>hi</div>
<div>hi</div>
<div>hi</div>
<div>hi</div>
<div id="click">click</div>
```

//

```
$("div").css("color", "red");
$("#click").click(function () {
    $("*").removeAttr("style");
});
```

Keep in mind James Bruckner's warning that this kills all inline styles that were hardcoded into the original HTML. Since Javascript changes CSS by manipulating the style attribute, there's no real way to distinguish what was original, and what was set programmatically. (EDIT. See the comments below.)

http://jsfiddle.net/FASvA/

Comment: You can also be safe by adding a modified class to the affected elements when a style has been altered, then run the selector on that class when needed. `$(".modified").removeAttr("style")`

Comment: Neat idea. Extra code, but if you want this functionality, that's a good way to avoid the problem.

Comment: I think this solution will work best for me, as none of my elements will have inline styles. Thank you!

Comment: or instead of using a class, you could also use the data-attribute.

Answer (score 2):

As an option you could store initial `style` attribute (`e._originalStyle = e.style.cssText`) in a private property and restore it when you'll need to drop all styles applied via javascript (`e.style.cssText = e._originalStyle`)