# Clear style on every DOM element

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to find a smart way of clearing previously changed style property on every DOM element.

I know there is a way to clear styles like this
(margin is just an example attribute):

```
element_name.style.margin = "";
```

Clearing many elements with many styles attributes this way will take ages, so I hope there is some "all_at_once" solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear all Javascript-applied styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796509/clear-all-javascript-applied-styles)

Comment: document. getElementsByTagName('*').removeAttribute('style');

Comment: @BenjaminRussell That will only work if the style was set inline withe the `style` attribute. It won't affect computed styles.

Comment: First, you'd need to set up your own way of tracking which elements get CSS changes and recording the element, the CSS property, and the original value. There is no such built-in way of doing that. Then, you could loop over that element list and restore the properties to their original values pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

This will clear the style of all tags:

```js
const tags = document.querySelectorAll("*");

for (let i of tags) {
     i.style = '';
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: beige">
  <span style="color: red">Hello</span>
  <p style="world">World</p>
</div>
```

You could also use `i.removeAttribute('style');` to remove the `style` attribute.

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName()` should rarely be used these days as it returns a live node list, which hurts performance. `.querySelectorAll()` is the better choice. Also, your solution will only clear the style if it was set inline with the `style` attribute. It won't clear any computed styles. This also changes every element and the OP says that they only want to change elements that have had changes.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thank you for your feedback. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the elements by using

```
document.querySelectorAll("*")
```

You will get an `object` with all the `elements` with numbered `keys`. `Object.keys` will give you an array of all the keys and with `forEach` you can iterate and apply the style or any manipulation to the elements.

```js
var elem = document.querySelectorAll("*");
Object.keys(elem).forEach((e)=>elem[e].style.margin = "32px")
```

```html
<div>scscs</div>
```

This can also be used

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
Object.keys(elem).forEach((e)=>elem[e].style.margin = "")
```

```html
<div>scscs</div>
```

The `document.getElementsByTagName("*");` shouldn't be used due to performance issues as mentioned by @ScottMarcus in comments

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName()` should rarely be used these days as it returns a live node list, which hurts performance. `.querySelectorAll()` is the better choice. Also, your solution will only clear the style if it was set inline with the `style` attribute. It won't clear any computed styles. This also changes every element and the OP says that they only want to change elements that have had changes.

Answer (score 0):

## [`.cssText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/cssText)

`.cssText` treats the whole value of `.style` as a string:

> ```
> document.documentElement.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(tag => tag.style.cssText = '');
> ```

This expression will collect all tags within the `<html>` tag and overwrite all `.style` properties.

### Demo

```js
document.documentElement.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(tag => tag.style.cssText = '');
```

```html
<div style='color:red'>RED</div>
<div style='color:red'>RED</div>
<div style='color:red'>RED</div>
<div style='color:red'>RED</div>
<div style='color:red'>RED</div>
<div style='color:red'>RED</div>
<div style='color:red'>RED</div>
<div style='color:red'>RED</div>
<div style='color:red'>RED</div>
<div style='color:red'>RED</div>
<div style='color:red'>RED</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove inline styles and disable stylesheets:

```js
function clearStyles() {
  // remove inline styles:
  document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(e => e.style = null);

  // disable stylesheets:
  Object.values(document.styleSheets).forEach(v => v.disabled = true);
}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: pink
}
```

```html
<h1 style="background:navy">My color was set in stylesheet<br>and background was set inline</h1>
<button onclick="clearStyles()">Clear styles</button>
```